# Have I used fscanf incorrectly?

Tags: c, file, matrix, scanf

I'm doing some coding in C for an assignment, and have encountered a strange problem. I have the following content saved in a txt-file:

```
11
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

It is just a square matrix of zeroes and ones, and the top number 11 is the dimensions of the matrix. I read this file using the following code snippet:

```
void generateCNF(FILE* f, FILE* g){
    int n;
    fscanf(f,"%d",&n);
    int i,j;
    int A[n][n]; // A is where I store my matrix
    for(i=1;i<=n;i+=1){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j+=1){
            fscanf(f,"%d",&A[i][j]); 
            printf("%d ",A[i][j]); // I print out A while reading into it
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //...
}
```

This is the output that printf generates:

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 44 0 1606415088
```

I have no idea how those last entries went so wrong. I tried opening the file with the matrix in a text editor, and it looked perfectly fine, so I suspect something is amiss with fscanf (or rather, my use of it).

I can add the complete C-file (around 90 lines) if that is necessary to help me, but I don't want to clutter the post unnecessarily.

Comment: Hint: always check return value of any scanf function. It'll save you a ton of headache at some point.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the title. `fscanf` works as documented.

Comment: @WeatherVane Approved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're indexing out of bounds of your matrix. If you don't crash, you're going to potentially get garbage because you're writing to memory you don't own. Arrays and Matrices in C are zero-indexed, so a size n by n matrix is indexed 0 through n-1.

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i+=1){
    for(j=1;j<=n;j+=1){
```

should be

```
for(i=0;i<n;i+=1){
    for(j=0;j<n;j+=1){
```

Answer (score 3):

Array indexes are based on zero, they go from zero to the number of elements minus one.

In your case they go from `0` to `n - 1` (inclusive). That means the loops should be e.g.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i+=1){
```

Notice that `i` starts at `0`, and the condition is changed from `i<=n` to `i<n`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your loop code with

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j+=1)
    {
        fscanf(f,"%d",&A[i][j]); 
        printf("%d ",A[i][j]); // I print out A while reading into it
       }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Look at the loop start and end point. In c, arrays start at index 0.